# can anyone explain why this async function giving error in python?? I'm newbie to async in python

Tags: python, asynchronous

```py
import asyncio
import time
from time import sleep

async def source_scraper(index):
    # sleep(1)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # print(index)

async def source_scraper_head_sub():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    links = [i for i in range(10_000)]
    start = time.time()
    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(None, source_scraper, index) for index in enumerate(links)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print("time taken =", time.time() - start)

def runner():
    asyncio.run(source_scraper_head_sub())

runner()
```

Output:

```
time taken = 0.4620068073272705
C:\Apps\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:1897: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'source_scraper' was never awaited
  handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: _coroutine 'source_scraper' was never awaited_: `tasks = [await loop.run_in_executor(None, source_scraper, index) for index in enumerate(links)]`

Comment: If you're a newbie to `async` in general, then simply using the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) may be simpler than trying to learn `async/await` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import time, sleep

def source_scraper(index):
    sleep(1)
    return index

def source_scraper_head_sub():
    links = [i for i in range(100)]
    start = time()
    with Pool() as p:
        tasks = p.map(source_scraper, links)
    print(f"time taken = {time() - start:.2f}")
    return tasks

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = source_scraper_head_sub()
    print(data[-5:])
```

Output:

```
time taken = 12.13
[95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing low-level event loop API with high-level `async`-`await` syntax.

`loop.run_in_executor` regards its argument as *normal* functions and simply calls them.

Conceptually, an `async def` is a callable that *returns* a coroutine.  So if you pass it to `run_in_executor` it gets called, the result (the coroutine) is discarded and never awaited, hence the warning.  On the other hand, `asyncio.gather` accepts a list of coroutines, so you can directly pass the result of calling `source_scraper` to it, without mentioning `loop`.

To quote [asyncio docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html):

> Application developers should typically use the high-level asyncio functions, such as asyncio.run(), and should rarely need to reference the loop object or call its methods.

#### With async/await (recommended)

Remove the call to `run_in_executor` and change the line `tasks = [...]` into

```py
tasks = [source_scraper(index) for index in enumerate(links)]
```

and everything runs in 1 second thanks to the non-blocking nature of `asyncio.sleep`.

#### With event loop API

If for some reason you want to use the event loop, change `source_scraper` to a normal function

```py
def source_scraper(index):
    sleep(1)
    print(index)
```

and keep everything else.  Beware this has different behavior than the previous approach.  `time.sleep` is blocking, and if the pool is not big enough --- each thread will have to handle more than one task sequentially, resulting longer running time.